# Lua операция с таблицей

Tags: массивы, динамические-массивы, lua, таблицы

```
  a = {{1,2,3,3,3},
      {4,5,6,6,6,6},
      {7,8,9,9,9,9,9}}

  b = {{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{3,6,9},{3,6,9},{3,6,9},{6,9},{9}}
```

Мне нужно из a получить b. Как это сделать?

Comment: Скажите, но зачем Вы взяли такой псевдоним? Вы смотрели советский мультфим "Приключения капитана Врунгеля"? Там есть такая классная фраза: "Как вы яхту назовете, так она и поплывёт"... Кстати, псевдоним раз в 30 дней можно сменить. Но это уж как Вы сами себе решите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто *повернуть* таблицу!
Для этого отражаем каждый элемент из `input[a][b]` в `output[b][#output[b] + 1]`

Выглядит это так:

```
function rotate(t) --- Определим функцию для поворота таблицы
    local result = {}   -- Определим результирующую таблицу
    for i = 1, #t do  -- Начнем цикл по всем 'строкам' таблицы
        for j = 1, #t[i] do   -- Начнем цикл по всем элементам 'строки'
            if #result < j then -- Если длина результирующей таблицы <                                
                result[j] = {}  -- текущего индекса - вставим в нее новую таблицу
            end
            result[j][#result[j] + 1] = t[i][j] -- Добавим новый элемент в текущую 'строку' результата
        end 
    end
    return result
end

function print_table(t) --- Просто функция для вывода результата
    local rows = #t
    for i = 1, rows do
        local cells = #t[i]
        for j = 1, cells do
            io.write(t[i][j], ' ')
        end
        io.write('\n')
    end
end

local before = { {1,2,3,3,3}, {4,5,6,6,6,6}, {7,8,9,9,9,9,9} } -- Ваша таблица
local after = rotate(before)

print_table(before)
print()
print()
print_table(after)
```

Вывод:

> 1 2 3 3 3 
>  4 5 6 6 6 6 
>  7 8 9 9 9 9 9
>
> 1 4 7 
>  2 5 8 
>  3 6 9 
>  3 6 9 
>  3 6 9 
>  6 9 
>  9

Comment: Если ответ помог Вам - не забудьте поставить галочку)

Comment: А можно чтоб было меньше кода функции rotate ?

Comment: @tormozzzz: не знаю, для чего Вам, но чуток сократил) Я убрал кэширование «длин» таблиц, так что в зависимости от реализации Lua-машины производительность может немного ухудшиться